# Dependency management not working with multi level inheritance

Tags: java, spring, maven

Let say I have a project named **parent** (type pom) which inherit **spring-boot-starter-parent**:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You can see that I have a dependency at *dependencyManagement*

Next, I create project **mid** that inherit **parent**:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>mid</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>emms-backend</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Finally, I create project **child** that inherit **mid**:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>mid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>child</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when I build the child with mvn install, I got an error that no version found for spring-boot-startter-webflux. If I put the line `<version>2.4.4</version>` to the dependency at **parent** project, it doesn't work either. If I put the line `<version>2.4.4</version>` to the dependency at **mid** project, it  work. but I expect that I do not need to put the version anywhere. Do I have wrong somewhere?

Comment: You need to use `mvn install` in the parent project (in your case `mid`) so the changes are applied to the child project.

Comment: Not the problem here bro

Answer (score 1):

The Maven documentation on [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) has the following warning (emphasis is mine):

> When referring to artifacts whose POMs have transitive dependencies, the project needs to specify versions of those artifacts as managed dependencies. **Not doing so results in a build failure since the artifact may not have a version specified**. (This should be considered a best practice in any case as it keeps the versions of artifacts from changing from one build to the next).

It looks like you're hitting this exact behavior.